# spring integration flow with jdbc output

Tags: spring-integration

I am looking to understand what is the best way to persist the output of an integration flow containing an aggregator (with release strategy spanning approx. 3 minutes) into a datasource.

I've been considering JDBC, but open to other options as well. Ideally I could use a spring integration component that deals well with buffered writes, maintaining jdbc connections with low overhead and that can operate at a spring data level (I want to work with a domain model not with raw SQL updates). 
JDCBOutboundGateway and JDBCMessageHandler seem to be limited by SQL direct 
interaction. 
I considered JDBCChanelMessageStore but seemed that would be limited by a binary representation of the messages. 
Is a service activator a more suited choice? Would I have to read service activator inputs from a pollable queue in order to ensure better write performance?

Transactional constraints are also under consideration for this integration flow with the goal to accommodate about 10K messages/hour.

Any directions are highly appreciated. Have been having trouble finding resources about JDBC output from integration flows (mostly mentions of jdbc message handlers and gateways without specific considerations for performance and data model flexibility).

Comment: I ended up using a MongoDbStoringMessageHandler at the end of my aggregation pipeline. Still unsure if there is JDBC solution.